# reprepro doesn't update packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, reprepro

I started using reprepro for a private repository and I set a distribution with the relative update config. Then I executed `reprepro update repo` and all has worked the first time, all the packages were downloaded and added to db.

Now I tried to manually delete a package and then I executed `reprepro update repo` without success. Then I tried `reprepro --noskipold update repo` but the removed package didn't come. Moreover I noticed the operation was really fast and probably it didn't check even other packages since I'm talking about a complete repo mirror (30k+ pkgs).

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself, it was a problem caused by `FilterList: deinstall ignore.list` directive which goal was to ignore some listed packages. Then I discovered that I needed `deinstall` parameter only within the list itself while I needed `install` parameter in `FilterList:`.

So the solution was `FilterList: install ignore.list`.